# Expand just one card from a group of cards

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui Card to display group of cards, This is my state:

```
state = {
    items: [],
    anchortEl: null,
    expand: false
}
```

"expand" is to flag when I click to expand a card or not.
And this is where the cards have to be displayed:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="outerDiv-favorites" >
            {
                this.state.items.length !== 0 ?
                    this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
                        <Grid>
                            <Card className="root" key={i}>
                                <CardMedia className='media' key="media">
                                    <img style={{ width: "100%", height: "150px" }}
                                        alt="SERVICE"
                                    />
                                </CardMedia>

                                <div
                                    className="card-header"
                                    key={item.name}
                                >{item.name}</div>

                                <CardActions key="action"
                                    style={{ padding: '0' }}
                                    className="card-actions"
                                >
                                    <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                                        <FavoriteIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                    <IconButton
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            this.setState({
                                                ...this.state,
                                                expand: !this.state.expand
                                            })
                                        }}>
                                        <ExpandMoreIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                </CardActions>

                                <Collapse in={this.state.expand} timeout="auto"
                                    unmountOnExit key="collapse">
                                    <CardContent key="content">
                                        <div>{item.description}</div>
                                    </CardContent>
                                </Collapse>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    ))
                    :
                    <div className="no-approval-data"><p>WAITING!</p></div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is an image how they are:
[image: screen1]

The problem is when I click to expand one card, all are expanded!
How to expand just the card I clicked?

[image]

Comment: It looks like all cards are using the same state to determine whether they are expanded or collapsed. If you want them expanded independently then they will each need their own unique expanded state.

Comment: I don't know the number of cards beacuse data is loaded from database. So I can't determine how many states I need!

Comment: Why can you just put the expand state in your items object array alongside name and description?

Comment: It didn't cross my mind! THANK YOU it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 1 expand state that is used by all cards. This means that if a user opens 1 card, the state will change and all other cards will also expand at the same time.

To fix this, each card needs its own unique expand state, for example:

```
state = {
    items: [
      {name: 'Foo', description: 'Foo is foo', expand: false},
      {name: 'Bar', description: 'Bar is bar', expand: true},
      {name: 'Tree', description: 'Tree is tree', expand: false},
    ],
    anchortEl: null,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height of card to min-content.if height of one card increases, the grid row height increases, and by default styling, card adjusts to height of row.So, setting it to min-content will ensure it doesn't adjust to grid-row-height.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.